# Angular Bootstrap Collapsible Column

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I was looking for a angular/bootstrap non javascript solution to have a collapsible bootstrap column..

Here's what I came up with when I couldn't find another solution online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was important to me to not use jquery (don't want to clutter up my controller with UI stuff)

It's not rocket science, but I spent a while looking for a bootstrap solution and came up dry.

```
<button ng-click="showAddDiv = !showAddDiv">Show</button>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="material-color-primary-1 col-xs-12" ng-class="{true:'col-lg-8', false:'col-lg-12'}[showAddDiv]" ng-init="showAddDiv = false">
    </div>

    <div class="material-color-secondary-1" ng-class="{true:'col-xs-12 col-lg-4', false:'hidden'}[showAddDiv]">
        'add div'
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well Angular is base on javascript and probably took some ideas from jQuery. You can use Angulars show / hide functions, is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @hogan I realize the jquery stuff I was trying to avoid is all being done by angular.  But I just didn't want someone checking through my code to need to decide what's ui-related and what's application related

Comment: Ok, so is your answer posted here the final answer or are you still lookinng for a solution? If secondary: What are you missing?

Comment: I'm happy with the solution, was going to leave it for others/my-future-self.  Can't mark it as correct for another day though